# getUserMedia how can i improve audio quality? How can I make audio to stop echoing?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, getusermedia

I been trying to work with webRTC for a few day. One of the problem that I faced since then is the audio quality. The audio from getUserMedia is horrible. It is echoing a lot. I have try all the constraint but still echoing. This is my code.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 300, height: 300, frameRate: 30 }, audio: { volume: 0.3, sampleSize: 16, sampleRate: 44100, echoCancellation: true, noiseSuppression: true }, })
```

I know that there is a way to make the audio quality better because a website like omegle use the same technology but they have very clear audio. So please if someone is kind enough to point me to the right direction to get the better audio, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you testing both sides of the call on the same side? If yes disable all the cancellation/suppression features and test it seperated or mute one side. The quality of gum is equivelant to your microphones quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the audio keep echoing is because both input audio and output audio came from the same device. If the local video is muted and only turn on the incoming audio, the echo disappeared. I hope this will help if anyone experience the same problem as mine.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will help but for audio constraints object I usually do this:

```
autoGainControl: false,
echoCancellation: false,
googAutoGainControl: false,
noiseSuppression: false
```

Maybe those few you seem to be missing are still causing issues. Does it sound bad in all browsers? Have you tried testing multiple microphones? Other than this I'm not sure because microphones sound great in my apps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Perry, 

Thanks a lot. It saved my one hour.

Comment: Thank you Perry! For anyone struggling with capturing desktop audio / tabCapture / desktopCapture and facing bad audio quality: Chrome runs DSP on audiooutput type devices and MediaStreams as well (even tho they are not coming from a mic). This leads to bad quality on captured system audio played-back and recorded. These constraints fix the issue.